# Who from the staff is in charge of selecting the music for each scene?

Tags: anime-production

I've been watching a lot of anime recently and realized whether the music fits a scene or not affects a lot in how much I like it, so... who's in charge of doing so?

Is it the Episode Director, the Series Director, the Sound Director or someone else? Or maybe it depends on the series?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read [this article by Justin Sevakis](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/answerman/2017-05-31/.116809) because it really varies and depends on the type of production committee.

TL;DR

1. Director or
2. Production Committee or
3. A music publisher (which is part of the production Committee) or
4. An entirely separate business unit within the production Committee.

> Anime opening and ending themes are a big deal not only for fans, but
>   for the creators, and the companies producing anime. Opening themes
>   are a show's "best foot forward," and the staff will usually put quite
>   a bit of effort into coming up with an impressive sequence for
>   whatever song is chosen. Anime production committees, the group of
>   companies putting up money to produce the show, often include a record
>   label or music publisher, and so those theme songs are valuable places
>   to promote their artists. Ads by Kiosked
>
> In some cases, the director will go into the project already wanting a
>   certain existing song, or wanting to work with a particular artist to
>   compose something specifically for their new project -- regardless of
>   whether that artist has anything to do with the companies on the
>   production committee. That's how we very occasionally get English
>   artists doing opening or closing themes. Other times, the production
>   committee will insist on using the songs to push a specific artist,
>   and the director just has to deal.
>
> The business of anime vocal tracks is nearly always facilitated by the
>   main production company or another business on the production
>   committee. Many major anime producers also have affiliated record
>   labels -- for example, Bandai Visual owns the record label Lantis,
>   while Aniplex itself is a division of Sony Music Japan. At an early
>   stage, the production committee has a meeting with the director of the
>   anime, and presents him with a pile of pop songs that are in
>   production. These songs are at "demo" stage -- meaning, they're not
>   done, and usually have a temporary vocal track. The director usually
>   just picks a song from that pile and uses it. They might tweak the
>   lyrics a little bit to fit the show better. The record label will then
>   go back and finish the song with the artist of their choosing, who may
>   or may not be a voice actor featured in the show. If a famous
>   (expensive) composer is doing the music for the show, they will often
>   be asked to contribute the theme songs, as they're likely to be hits
>   no matter who sings them.
>
> The business of anime songs is a huge one, and operates as a market
>   separate from the rest of the Japanese music scene. The selection of
>   song and artist is therefore usually a business decision.

Comment: Thank you, this is really interesting... However, this is for opening and ending themes, not for OSTs. I've read interviews with Yoko Kanno where she states she gets told how a scene will go and then she has to imagine the music that goes there. So the question is, who tells her that? And I imagine Yoko Kanno does it in a different way since she often produces a ton of music for each series (in a way that the tracks are almost never repeated unless it's a character's theme).